# Using regex to find all code identified with 4 spaces

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a textarea, similar to StackOverflow, I'd like to wrap code (indented by 4 spaces) with a pre/code block. I'm trying to use the following regex to find the code:

```
re = / # Match a MARKDOWN CODE section.
    (\r?\n)              # $1: CODE must be preceded by blank line
    (                    # $2: CODE contents
      (?:                # Group for multiple lines of code.
        (?:\r?\n)+       # Each line preceded by a newline,
        (?:[ ]{4}|\t).*  # and begins with four spaces or tab.
      )+                 # One or more CODE lines
      \r?\n              # CODE folowed by blank line.
    )                    # End $2: CODE contents
    (?=\r?\n)            # CODE folowed by blank line.
    /x
result = subject.gsub(re, '\1<pre>\2</pre>')
```

But this isn't working, here's the example in Rubular:

http://rubular.com/r/l5faSjR8ya

Any suggestions on how to have this Regex, match the code allow me to wrap a pre/code tags around the code? Thanks

Comment: It would be great to be able just fix the orig regex: http://rubular.com/r/KyksYmQOI2   --- For some reason if finds a false match in the beginning.

Comment: Remove the beginning `(\r?\n)`?

Comment: This is another case that would probably be done a lot easier using a HTML parser. I suggest reading through questions about [Nokogiri and HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nokogiri+html). A regex is not a good tool for HTML or XML due to their freeform nature.

Comment: @theTinMan are you sure? Nokogiri seams to parse XML like documents but in this case the input is text without tags but with indented lines.

Comment: @MattiasWadman Looking at it again, probably not. The OP has been dancing around this same issue in four different questions, so I lost track which I was looking at. I do think that a regex is probably not the best solution though.

Comment: Ah ok :) But your probably right that regex is not the best solution for this, maybe a simple solution if indent is the only syntax that is  needed... but then later on: ok just one more syntax features... and one more... and some tags :)

Comment: @MattiasWadman,@theTinMan - I added a solution (regex) in my **edit** that does the job. It's not easy but it duplicates the editor here at SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an escape out of the code mode with any trailing newline not followed by tab or 4 spaces. Not sure but successive newlines would not be included in the code block.

I don't get Ruby's regex options too well, but this seems to work:  http://rubular.com/r/BlbreoO3sn

`((?:^(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*$(?:\r?\n|\z))+)` Theorhetically, its in multi-line mode.

Just make the replacement `<pre>\1</pre>`

**EDIT**
@Rachela Meadows - After further examination, this is a fairly difficult regex.
I managed to exactly duplicate the functionality of the `<pre><code>` block features of the online editor here on SO.

After obtaining each block and before wrapping in a `<pre><code>`, all markup entities should be converted (ie; like `<` to `&lt;`, etc). That being said, I didn't do that step in the Ruby code sample below. I do have the regex's to do that though.

A special note about trimming: The main regex below does not include residual trailing newlines. Nor does the SO functionality. So the code block is correct top to bottom.
However, the leading 4 spaces (or tab) that *could* be contained in the body can't be trimmed (and they should be) in the main regex. For that it needs a callback.

Playing around with the `gsub` *block* mode, its easy to trim those leading spaces/tab.

Let me know if you have any problems with this.

Links -
Rubular (for the regex): http://rubular.com/r/pp9oRLQ0xo
Ideone (for the working Ruby code): http://ideone.com/aA9it

Regex compressed -
`(^\s*$\n|\A)(^(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*[^\s].*$\n?(?:(?:^\s*$\n?)*^(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*[^\s].*$\n?)*)`

Regex expanded -

```
(^\s*$\n|\A)                                # Capt grp 1, block is preceeded by a blank line or begin of string
(                                           # Begin "Capture group 2", start of pre/code block
   ^(?:[ ]{4}|\t) .* [^\s] .* $ \n?            # First line of code block (note - lines must contain at least 1 non-whitespace character)
   (?:                                         # Start "Optionally, get more lines of code"
       (?: ^ \s* $ \n? )*                         # Many optional blank lines
       ^(?:[ ]{4}|\t) .* [^\s] .* $ \n?           # Another line of code 
   )*                                          # End "Optionally, get more lines of code", do 0 or more times
)                                           # End "Capture group 2", end of pre/code block
```

Ruby code -

```
regex = /(^\s*$\n|\A)(^(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*[^\s].*$\n?(?:(?:^\s*$\n?)*^(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*[^\s].*$\n?)*)/;

data = '
Hello Worldsasdasdffasdfasdf  asdf

    thisdqweee

    asdfasdfasdfasdf
sdfg

    #YYYY {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    }


    #ZZZZZZ {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }';


# ---
result = data.gsub(regex) {
   ||
   x=$2;
     ## Construct the return value '\1<pre><code>\2</code></pre>'.
     ## But, trim each line with 1 to 4 leading spaces (or a tab with regex on the bottom).
     ## They are not necessary now, they are replaced with a code block.

   $1 + '<pre><code>' +   x.gsub(/^[ ]{1,4}/, '') + '</code></pre>'
};

# Note - Tabs can be trimed too, use : x.gsub(/^(?:[ ]{1,4}|\t)/,'') in the above

print result;
```

Comment: Thanks, how do you do the replacements?

Comment: This is removing everything that's not code which isn't good. I'd like to keep the original text just wrap code in the <pre> tag?

Comment: @Rachela Meadows - Added revised regex and a Ruby code sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to match full lines, don't explicitly match for `(?:\r?\n)+`, rather use `^` and `$`. Try

```
(\r?\n)((?:(?:^[ ]{4}|\t).*$)+)(?=\r?\n)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but that is not matching each line individually, making each line of code have <pre></pre> wrapped around each live versus once around the entire code block?

Comment: I think you need explicitly match the new line if you want the capture group to span multiple lines, or?

Comment: @MattiasWadman Im not sure I understand the question. But given a block of code, I would like to wrap it once with a <pre> tag like StackOverflow does when you indent w 4 spaces. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Im think your pattern require two new lines in the beginning to match.

Maybe like this? `((?:(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*(?:\r?\n|$))+)`?
$ is used to match if last line is indented and have not new line)

http://rubular.com/r/Vg9HnJpjbw

Ruby:

```
s = "before\n    indent1\n    indent2\nmiddle\n     indent1\nafter"
p s.gsub(/((?:(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*(?:\r?\n|$))+)/x, '<pre>\1</pre>')
```

Output:

```
"before\n<pre>    indent1\n    indent2\n</pre>middle\n<pre>     indent1\n</pre>after"
```

Comment: Thanks but that's finding a false match, see example: http://rubular.com/r/jATXftOHTV

Comment: You mean "dont't get me"? I does not seam to match that when i look hmm

Comment: It would be great to be able just fix the orig regex: rubular.com/r/KyksYmQOI2 --- For some reason if finds a false match in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your newline captures is redundant. You can use `^` and `$` with the `s` flag turned off to match EOL rather than EOL, this is a better pattern than trying to match newlines.

Try this pattern:

```
/(?:^(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*$[\n\r]*)+/
```

Comment: Thanks @ʞɔıu but that results in no actual matches? http://rubular.com/r/AC2KnhhNLU

Comment: ? it works in that link for me. It's supposed to highlight the part in between "Normal P start" and "Normal P end", right?

Comment: Correct, but if you look at the rubular link, you'll see no matches are found when it should find 1, the code: http://rubular.com/r/AC2KnhhNLU

Comment: Oh, that doesn't mean no matches were found, that means there were no subgroup expressions found. The whole matched area (the highlighted area) is implicitly group 0. So you could do like `subject.gsub(re, '<pre>\0</pre>')`